# Overwrite object element (from queryset) with another object (from a different queryset) for json encoding

Tags: python, django

Please excuse what may become evident to be python noobness. Here's a view function.  Its a jsonp response, and works exactly as required, brilliant (some elements amended for anonimity).

**Updated: This is my function, complete.**

```
class stores(ListView):
    model = Store

    def get_queryset(self):

        args = [Q()]
        output = []

        callback = self.request.GET.get('callback', False)
        region = self.request.GET.get('region', False)
        country = self.request.GET.get('country', False)

        if region:
            args.append(Q(country__region_id=int(region)))

        if country:
            args.append(Q(country=int(country)))

        outputs =  self.model.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, args))

        for i, item in enumerate(outputs):
            outputs[i].contacts = pk__in=list(list(Contact.objects.filter(store=item.id).values()))

        return '%s(%s)' % (callback, json) if callback != False else json
```

**This is a response that i get from the script**

```
[{"pk": 2837, "model": "store.store", "fields": {"geolocation": "-30.8040344,111.8395886", "code": "", "logo": "dist/logo/theshop_Sykes_9.jpg", "photo": "", "postcode": "2222/1111", "openinghours": "", "exclude": false, "city": "Perth", "dealer_type": "distrib", "contacts": "[{'phone': u' +1111 7000', 'fax': u'+61 2222 2122', 'type': u'general', 'email': u'notworking@theshop.com'}, {'phone': u'+61 2222 1111', 'fax': u'+61 1111 2222', 'type': u'general', 'email': u'notworking@theshop.com'}]", "servedcountries": [{"lat": "-25.244398", "lng": "132.775136", "name": "Oz"}], "comments": "", "state": "", "latitude": "-31.8040344", "legal_store": "theshop Pty Ltd", "updated": "2013-08-06T15:11:15Z", "street1": "thehouse", "street2": "Landsdale", "street3": "", "phone": "", "address": "The house", "product_type": [], "name": "theshop Pty Ltd", "sectors": "Industrial", "created": "2013-08-06T13:50:48Z", "url": "http://www.theshopsykes.com/", "country": {"lat": "-25.274398", "lng": "133.775136", "name": "Australia"}, "longitude": "115.8395886", "local_store": "theshop Pty Ltd"}}]
```

Paste that string into a json decoder like the one at http://json.parser.online.fr/

You'll see that the contacts element is not correctly parsed.

**I have tried:**

```
outputs[i].contacts = serializers.serialize("json", Contact.objects.filter(distributor=item.id), use_natural_keys=True)
```

But i get an Error.

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Here is the model declaration, in case it'll help.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_type = models.CharField('Email Type', max_length='20', choices=(('sales', 'Sales'), ('support', 'Support'), ('general', 'General')), blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField('Phone Number', max_length=200, blank=True)
    fax = models.CharField('Fax Number', max_length=200, blank=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.contact_type

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.contact_type
```

Comment: Not sure that I follow what kind of output you are expecting. Do you want to add a .contact property on each Store matching your request ?

Comment: Yes. I want a contact property on each store, containing all the contacts at each store. This is basically happening already, except that the data is apparently already serialised before it is json encoded, meaning that the contacts property is not iterable by the receiving script (in this instance, an angularjs project).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are looking to serialize related objects (Contacts, related to Store).

As this is a non-trivial question, I would suggest having a look at something like https://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers — not sure if there are more recent options in Django core as well (select_related ?).

Cheers,

Comment: I actually think that contacts are already being serialized.  I want them to be serialized with the rest of the data, where the json encoding is performed.   I think what i want is to convert a queryset to a dictionary.

Comment: Well. The queryset is a collection of objects. So you want to be able to convert an object to a dictionary. Which means that you want to serialize them :-) Related to your interests: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#dependencies-during-serialization

Comment: I really appreciate your help thusfar.  However, i'm still completely baffled. I wish I wasn't, believe me - and I'm trying to conceptualize this so I fix it myself.  Have tried a few things that make sense to me, but getting all manner of issues...  "outputs[i].contacts = serializers.serialize("json", Contact.objects.filter(store=item.id), use_natural_keys=True)" results in "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'".  Other attempts have had similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Steve, I think your thinking about how serialization works is flawed. I envision a process of getting from a queryset to a JSON response as a two-step process, and the Django serializer does both.

1) Turning a queryset into a a dictionary of strings and numbers.
2) Turning that dictionary into JSON.

Step 1 is harder than one thinks. E.g. a serializer will have to decide which attributes are serialized. E.g. if you'd define a property on the model, it seems like they're being serialized (otherwise contacts wouldn't show up). I was expecting that the Django serializer only serializes model fields, but I guess not!

It also has to make decisions about how to present relationships to other models. This is called nesting, and there's multiple options: Just list the primary keys of the related model, or include serialized versions of it. One can do just list primary keys of related models, or include one or more levels of depth.

--

As far as solving your problem goes, I can suggest two things:

- As madflo suggested, the Django serializer might be too basic for your needs. I'd have a look at what else is available. Personally, I'm a big fan of Django Rest Framework; but that might be overkill for your use case. Their documentation regarding nesting might still be useful.
- I'd have a good look at the differences between `servedcountries` and `contacts`. It seems `servedcountries` is a related model that is getting serialized as expected, so find out why that is the case and `contacts` isn't. It would be helpful to include the declaration of the Store model.

Remark:

I'm not so sure about this line; I think you meant `pk__in_list`?

```
outputs[i].contacts = pk__in=list(list(Contact.objects.filter(store=item.id).values()))
```

Anyhow, if I understand it correctly, you should be able to replace it by

```
outputs[i].contacts = Contacts.objects.filter(store=item.id).values_list('pk', flat=True)
```